# Removing Windows 7 file encryption pop-up

Tags: windows-7, encryption, efs

[image]

I've started receiving this pop-up a couple of days ago, and it's annoying. To the best of my knowledge, I have not installed anything recently, nor have I dealt with EFS in any manner.

Following advice in other similar questions, I tried finding out if there are any encrypted files on my system, by doing this in administrative command prompt (for all my drives, C, E, and X):

`cipher /s:C:\ |findstr "^E"`

`cipher /s:C:\ /h | findstr "^.E"`

`cipher /u /n`

And all of them came back empty.

I decided to check the Certificate Management Tool / certmgr.exe, and found one certificate under Personal > Certificates, with the Intended purposes value set to Encrypting File System. Opening the certificate, I can see that the validity is from the 11th of May 2020, until the 17th of April **2120**.

Can I safely delete this certificate, and will that stop and prevent the pop-up from returning? Will this also disable the use of EFS, or do I have to do anything inside the Group Policy?

Comment: So what does the pop-up look like? You dive into some details, but the information about the very thing that brought you here is missing.

Comment: Added the screenshot, apologies for not including it the first time.

Comment: "Can I safely delete this certificate, and will that stop and prevent the pop-up from returning?" - **If you disable this certificate any files encrypted by this certificate will be permanently lost.** You should identify which files are encrypted, with the certificate you wish to delete, and disable EFS within your profile. If you do disable EFS, any file that is encrypted, cannot be decrypted. So the best way to prevent this prompt, is to actually backup your certificate, in the event it's actually required.  **You have been warned** EFS was enabled on May 11th 2020 according to certificate

Comment: As for disabling EFS with a group policy, based on the information you provided, it's not clear if that will be required.  The fact the certificate exists means, at some point EFS was enabled, which only happens through user interaction.

Comment: @Ramhound cipher.exe returned nothing (the syntax used is in the body of my question). Is this a clear indicator that nothing is encrypted, or should I look for another way of discovering encrypted files? Are there any other ways of discovering encrypted files?

Comment: Backup the certificate then delete it.  That’s the only action I will suggest doing in a case like this.